# {} makes my display settings pop up in an AHK script

Tags: autohotkey

Okay. I made some shortcuts for coding in JavaScript. Something like:

::fn:: = () => {};

But the curly braces don’t show up, and then my windows 10 side bar pops up for what I want to do with multiple displays. But I don’t even have multiple displays connected. How can I make this better?

Also, is there a way to set the keyboard cursor after AHK replaces text? For example to have the cursor in between the brackets after correction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces are parsed for special key names, mouse actions and other stuff.

You can use the `R` option to disable curly braces being parsed:

```
:R:fn:: = () => {};
```

You can also set the cursor inside the brackets like this:

```
::fn::
SendRaw () => {} ; Send the replacement text
Send {Left}      ; Press the left key once
Return
```